# How to get output image using OpenGL filter in Windows.?

Tags: c++, c, windows, opengl

I want to implement image filter in OpenGL.I knew GPUImage filter like sketchfilter in IOS.But I want to implement GPUImage filter  in windows platform using OpenGL.

My input image below

[image: My Input image]

Here I want to get below output image

[image]

How will I get above output image using OpenGL.?

Is there any open source code for filter in OpenGL.?

please help and give any suggestions.?

Comment: Why are you sure that you need OpenGL? Why not just do it on CPU ;-)

Comment: That question are actually two questions in one: a) what filter(s) (and parameters) was/were used to produce which output, b) how to implement image filtering in OpenGL. And both sub-questions are too broad for this site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But actually did not know filter for output image.But it is in IOS GPUimage framework the name is "SketchFilter".I want implement just any one filter in OpenGL. Give any one sample OpenGL filter.?

Comment: @2vision2: Actually there are no filters in OpenGL per se. You can use a fragment shader to implement filters, but this is not as simple as making a call "apply_filter".

Comment: @2vision2: Actually the picture above looks very much like as if a so called "sobel filter" got applied.